# why parameter pack expansion is so limited?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering, why parameter pack expansion is so limited in C++11 - is it just oversight in C++11 standard? Why is it not possible to do just `bar(args)...;`? It is possible to workaround that better than I did?

```
#include <iostream>

int bar(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << ' ';
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
void boo(T t)
{
    bar(t);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void boo(T t, Args&&... args)
{
    bar(t);
    boo(args...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void dummy(Args&&... args)
{
}

template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    dummy(bar(args)...);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    int dummy1[sizeof...(Args)] = { (bar(args), 0)... };

    std::cout << std::endl;

    boo(args...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 3, 5);
}
```

Comment: Probably because of potential ambiguity. Also, C++ has a habit of implementing the least possible amount of functionality required to make something not entirely impossible.

Comment: "You just pay for what you use", is that correct?

Comment: Rename "dummy" to "for_each_arg", and you've got a winner. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant note that bar() has to return something, so there would need to be more code to wrap void functions

Comment: Yup, I'm familiar with that...

Answer (score 3):

[The reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) mentions the different contexts in which parameter pack expansions are allowed. So, a slightly more succinct way of doing this is

```
auto a = {bar(args)...};
```

This won't work if the return type of bar is void.

Comment: To get it to handle `void` return type, and a potential comma operator overload, use `auto a = {(bar(args)..., void(), 0)};`

Comment: @Praetorian:  That is very cool, but you have a slight syntax error:  `auto a = {(bar(args), void(), 0)...};`

Comment: @HowardHinnant and you should end it with a `,0`, in case `args...` is empty.