# How to expand parameter pack of base classes and call member function of each one?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to use variadic templates for class composition. The idea is that the `Composer` class simply aggregates a number of variables and forwards function calls to all instantiated variables.

Firstly I am using the following simple wrapper class:

```
template< typename T >
struct WrapperType
{
    typedef T wrapped_type;
    typedef typename wrapped_type::value_type value_type;
    wrapped_type wrapee_;

    WrapperType() : wrapee_{}
    {}
};
```

This is used with the following `Composer` class, which hopefully derives from `WrapperType` instantiated for each type in the parameter pack `Args`:

```
template< typename... Args >
struct Composer : public WrapperType<Args>...
{
    Composer() : WrapperType<Args>{}...
    {}

    void display()
    {
        ((WrapperType<Args>...)::wrapee_).display();   // HOW?
    }
};
```

Assuming every wrapped type has a `display()` member function, how can I call the `display()` function for every type in the parameter pack?

I.E. If I have:

```
Composer< T1, T2, T3 > myComposer{};
myComposer.display();
```

I would like `myComposer.display()` to call `display()` for `T1`, `T2`, `T3`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why parameter pack expansion is so limited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316654/why-parameter-pack-expansion-is-so-limited)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only few contexts where *pack-expansion* can occur ([[temp.variadic] / p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#5)).

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you can't create *pack-expansion* from a function call, but you can expand it i.e. within an array *initializer-list*:

```
void display()
{
    using discard = int[];
    (void)discard{ 0, ((void)WrapperType<Args>::wrapee_.display(), 1)... };
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FsCs06xIOHwQ4QCp)

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) one can use *fold-expressions*:

```
void display()
{
    (WrapperType<Args>::wrapee_.display(), ...);
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gIywaR8aLYecM4Av)

Comment: Thanks that looks quite elegant. I was thinking about converting the parameter pack to a  boost::mpl::vector and using boost::mpl::for_each - but I think this is cleaner.